# C - append two structs to a single buffer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, buffer, memcpy

I need to make it so that the content of two structs will be inside a single buffer the size of the two structs. I need to use memcpy to do so.

This is my current code:

```
struct Header header;
struct Data_Format DF;

char *buffer[28];

header.Start = 0x7E;
header.Options = 0x00;

DF.Address = 0x007CB;
DF.Result = 0x105BA;

memcpy(buffer,&header,sizeof(header));
```

how do i make it so that the DF struct will continue where the header finished?

Comment: Using pointer arithmetic and the `sizeof` operator?

Comment: Also note that you declare `buffer` to be an array of 28 *pointers* to characters, probably not what you want.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Then should it simply be "char buffer[28]" to be a 28 byte buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
char buffer[sizeof(header)+sizeof(DF)];
...
memcpy(buffer,&header,sizeof(header));
memcpy(buffer+sizeof(header),&DF,sizeof(DF));
```

Comment: If `buffer` is not a pointer to something of size 1, you can do `memcpy((char *)buffer+sizeof(header),&DF,sizeof(DF));`, or (in gcc) cast to `void *`

Comment: @abligh: Of course you can cast it, but that sort of answer would miss OP's obvious mistake of using an array of `char` pointers to begin with.

Comment: @abligh thanks! it worked! But i have another quick question, i was told to print it with a for loop, but when i did that, i got a relaly bizzar result:

Comment: @CakeToppings: How exactly are you printing it?

Comment: @barakmanos
this is a continue comment, for some reason it just sent it.

lets say the value of header is: CCCCCC7E
and lets say the value of DF is: 01020304,

shouldnt the value of the buffer be "CCCCCC7E01020304"?
for some reason when i printed it i got: "7EFFFFFFCCFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFF..." and it goes on like that for a for like a couple dozen more characters.

this is how i printed it:

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++){
  printf("%02X", buffer[i]);
}
sorry for the messy comment im still new to this, i have no clue on how to align it properly

Comment: @CakeToppings: 1. It is unreadable here. Put it on a separate question and explain it properly please. 2. My name is not 'abligh' as you may have noticed (unless you have a specific reason for asking him or her at the comments to my answer).

Comment: @barakmanos yeah i noticed, sorry about that, i probably slipped from the b and just pressed a and then automatically pressed tab without even bothering to check it.

Comment: @barakmanos i posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760847/c-why-is-my-buffer-not-printing-properly

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer avoiding pointer arithmetic:

```
typedef struct data {
    struct Header header;
    struct Data_Format DF;
} data_t;

data_t buffer;

...

memcpy (&buffer.header, header, sizeof(Header));
memcpy (&buffer.DF, DF, sizeof(Data_Format));
```

Of course you could use the `struct` components of the outer structs and avoid the `memcpy` entirely.

You may well want to add `__attribute__(packed)` to the `struct` to ensure no space is taken by padding.

Comment: You could do simple assignment for that: `buffer.header = header; buffer.DF = DF;`

Answer (score 0):

just add another memcpy

```
memcpy(buffer + sizeof(header),&DF,sizeof(DF));
```

and also take care of the point mentioned by  @Joachim Pileborg
as you may not be needing an array of pointers.