# C - Why is my buffer not printing properly?

Tags: c, printf, hex, buffer

I have two objects, Header, and DF.
lets say

`header = CCCCCC7E`

and

`DF = 01020304`,

shouldnt the value of the buffer be `CCCCCC7E01020304`?

for some reason when i printed it i got:

`7EFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCCFFFFFFCC00FFFF
FFCC00000000000004030201FFFFFF8967341200000000`

this is how i printed it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)
{ printf("%02X", buffer[i]); }
```

this is the code:

```
    struct Header header;
    struct Data_Format DF;
    unsigned char buffer[TOTAL_SIZE];

    header.Start = 0x7E;
    header.Options = 0x00;
    header.PacketLength = 0x00;
    header.VCP = 0x00;
    header.Reserved = 0x00;
    header.Return = 0x00;

    DF.Address = 0x01020304; //real value: NULL
    DF.Result = 0x1234; //real value: NULL
    DF.Size = 0x6789; //real value: NULL

    memcpy(buffer,&header, sizeof(Header));
    memcpy(buffer+sizeof(Header), &DF, sizeof(Data_Format));
```

Comment: Show us the code where `buffer` is declared and filled

Comment: partial code not give any idea about final output.

Comment: Not enough code or information in your question, I suggest please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A `struct` may contain padding bytes (garbage), `memcpy`ing and printing garbage doesn't seems a good idea, instead, copy the members of the `struct`

Comment: Compare a printout of `sizeof(struct Header)` and `sizeof(struct Data_Format)` and compare that to what you expect. You might have padding issues. Also, if the buffer is larger than the size of the two structures, you will print uninitialized data.

Comment: Show how you declared the fields type within `struct Header` and `struct Data_Format`, you might have signedness issues

Answer (score 2):

From the partial code given it doesn't give much idea but Some point need to do.

Do a memset always before coping to the buffer.

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer))
```

This will prevent you to get the junk.

Comment: Batter this should be as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are not neccessarily packed together. Acctually, most compilers allign objects at 8 bytes border so that the data will be accessed at higher speed. The bytes between the objects will just be leaved uninitialized (sometimes the debug-version of runtime environment will fill the gap with invalid data).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper way [because of compiler optimizations and alignment] to achieve what you want.

However, just for a logical suggestion, in your code, change

`for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)`

to

`for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(Header) + sizeof(Data_Format)); i++)`.

This will limit the loop till valid entries. Remember, even after this change you're not guaranteed [actually,not supposed to] get the proper result.

---

**EDIT**

you can achieve your target using [`snprintf()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/snprintf/). A common usage looks like

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%x%x%x", header.start, header.options, DF.size);  //incomplete list
printf("%s", buf);
```

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer as it does not solve the OP issue: the output will still be "garbage"

Comment: Your edit does propose a solution: downvote removed :)